# create folders from each line of a textfile in bat

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a text file as follows:

**file.txt**

```
1. Adams Johnson - VB
2. Mike Robert - C++
3. victor -java
... and so on for almost 700 entries in that text file
```

I have to create folders with each line of this text file using a batch file.

I have tried the following code:

```dos
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (file.txt) do (

mkdir %%a

)
```

but my folders are created as follows:

```
1
2
3
... so on...
Adams 
Johnson
Mike 
Robert
Victor 
... so on...
```

I want it something like this:

```
1. Adams Johnson - VB
2. Mike Robert - C++
3. victor -java
... and so on.
```

How can I get that?

Answer (score 5):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (file.txt) do (

mkdir "%%a"

)
```

Space is a default separator, so `mkdir` (or `md` - they're equivalent) thinks you want this one and that one and the other one.

Actually, I'd prefer `"delims="` over `"tokens=*"` but if it works for you...

Comment: +1 For the `"delims="` comment to get the entire line, as is the intent. `"tokens=*"` is similar, except it also trims leading spaces.

Comment: @Nagarajan : I would not know how to start on a mac. You should create your own question - no doubt someone will respond.